# Exluding certain values in a matrix and matching it with another matrix it is based on?

Tags: python, matrix

I have two matrices, one with data and another with its flags (either True or False) of the same shape.
I want to somehow remove/disregard the true values in the flags matrix, and give the data the same shape with the new flag matrix without any trues.

In other words, I want a data set without any indices that are flagged as true.

Their shapes are (82680, 1, 1024, 4). Any method would be appreciated.

```
uvraw.data_array #data matrix
uvraw.flags_array #flags matrix (same shape)
```

I originally tried something like this:

```
flags = uvraw.flag_array
flag = []
for index, f in enumerate(flags):
    if np.any(f):
        flag.append(index)

data = uvraw.data_array
uvraw_noflags = np.sum(data(~flags))
```

but i know i did the index part and the last line wrong. Can anyone help me with something that somehow sets a new matrix with all values except the indices noted in flag.

Update: the end point for all of this is to be able to run a line of code something like "np.sum(~flags)" in which i take the sum of all relevant data, and average it.

Comment: Can you share sample inputs ?

Comment: can you give a sample input and an out put of what you want to do?

Comment: added a sample of what I want to do. Any other method would be appreciated as well.